# Подсчет символов в строке

Tags: java

Есть строка, например, такая: `String someText = "qdvbText."` Каким образом можно подсчитать количество символов в этой строке? Но есть условие: нужно подсчитать только символы в слове `Text`, т.е. до точки. Еще есть переменная, например: String firstchar = "T", т.е. она хранит первый символ в слове, символы которого нужно сосчитать. Таким образом, нужно подсчитать количество символов до точки, но включая этот первый известный символ, т.е. переменную firstchar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот код, который вырежет необходимую тебе строку:

```
String someText = "qdvbText.";
String firstchar = "T";
String resultStr = str.substring(str.indexOf(firstchar), str.indexOf('.'));
```

А как посчитать кол-во символов в строке, думаю, у Вас не составит труда. :)

Comment: >str.indexOf(firstchar) + 1      
не нужно делать +1

Comment: Верное замечание! Щас обновлю :)